# Good review articles on microwave hardware for superconducting qubit quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request, architecture, superconducting-quantum-computing, experimental-realization

I am trying to find some review articles on the microwave hardware used in superconducting qubit quantum computing.

So far, most papers that I found seem to be high level overviews, e.g., [Multilayer microwave integrated quantum circuits for scalable quantum computing](https://www.nature.com/articles/npjqi20162).
I am more interested in specific designs and challenges of the waveguides/transmission lines, cavities, signal interconnects, etc. used as hardware together with superconducting qubits.

Could anyone provide some review articles or seminars about the specific designs of the hardware/architecture?

Answer (score 3):

Are you interested more in the on-chip aspects of microwave HW, inside the fridge or room temperature components?

In any case, this paper:
[Microwaves in Quantum Computing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9318753) is a good overall reference, and I am guessing some of the references there can get you started on going more deeply.

If you're interested in cryogenic aspects of microwave HW (which are of course closely related), I can recommend [Engineering cryogenic setups for 100-qubit scale superconducting circuit systems](https://epjquantumtechnology.springeropen.com/articles/10.1140/epjqt/s40507-019-0072-0).

Finally, [A practical guide for building superconducting quantum devices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.06173.pdf) has useful discussions on both the on-chip aspects of microwave HW as well as the cryogenic considerations.